# Can't access htdocs with static IP address from browser

Tags: joomla, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I created a Joomla instance using Lightsail. Using FileZilla I transferred my html files in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs.

However when I enter my static IP address in my browser I always end up on this home page.

[image]

And if I try to redirect towards a file in my htdoc I end up on this one.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED:

So it appears the directory I was using wasn't the right one.

You need to use: /opt/bitnami/apps/joomla/htdocs.